# Why is this redirection not working in Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel

My button URL is : `<a href="{{url('cvs/create')}}" class="btn btn-success"> Nouveau Cv</a>`

It redirects me to : `http://localhost:8000/cvs/create`, normal.

But my page is in reality : `Route::get('/cvs/{id}', 'InfosController@indexe');` where I can visualize information about any CV

Why is that happening?

Here is a list of all my routes:

```
Route::post('/infos', 'InfosController@store');

Route::get('/cvs/{id}', 'InfosController@indexe');

Route::get('/cvs','CVController@index');

Route::get('/cvs/create','CVController@create');

Route::post('/cvs','CVController@store');

Route::get('/cvs/{id}/edit','CVController@edit');

Route::put('/cvs/{id}','CVController@update');

Route::delete('/cvs/{id}','CVController@destroy');
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You probably just need to move

```
Route::get('/cvs/create','CVController@create')
```

above

```
Route::get('/cvs/{id}', 'InfosController@indexe')
```

The routes are processed top-down, so when Laravel sees

```
'/cvs/create'
```

it's matching the

```
'cvs/{id}'
```

route and sending the request to 'InfosController@index. It never gets to your intended route.

Hope that helps!

Comment: Thank you. but when i do my :
Route::get('/cvs/{id}', 'InfosController@indexe'); don't work anymore

Comment: try using this `Route::get('/cvs/{id?}', 'InfosController@indexe');`

Comment: @HabibQadoos What changes the question mark in the route?

Comment: @Phil795 https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/routing#parameters-optional-parameters it makes the parameter optional